# PHP iconv_strlen function display problem

Tags: php, iconv

In the code below I'm trying to get the bytes for the character `こ` which should be 3 for the first function but I keep getting the value of 1 for each iconv_strlen function below. How can I figure out why this is?

Here is the code:

```
echo iconv_strlen("こ") . '<br />';
echo iconv_strlen("こ", "UTF-8") . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct value in first case is 1, not 3.
If you want to get count of bytes, you can use `strlen()` function, or change `iconv.internal_encoding` directive in php.ini or by `ini_set()` (to `ISO-8859-1`) - but it will affect all `iconv`-functions, so I recommend to use `strlen()`.

Comment: hm.. I checked it - result is 3.

Comment: @SyFY `$ php -r 'echo strlen("こ");'` → `3` Something's wrong with the way you're saving that "こ" then.

Comment: @deceze what exactly could be wrong I pasted your echo strlen("こ"); and I still get 1

Comment: @SyFY check in IDE or editor, that encoding of file is UTF-8.

Comment: @SyFY well... depends on editor. Usually this info can be found in bottom line (kind of 'status bar'), or in menu 'File -> Properties'.

Comment: what about netbeans or notepad++